# How to parse JSON response to show Image and Webview.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview

I have the JSON Response in this format:

{“ContentPage”: {“ContentImage”: “avdsfg.png”, “Content”: “have html data ” } }

How do I parse the response so as to get the Image and Content for the Imageview and webView respectively in iOS. Guidance needed. A Beginner in iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: You are already have parsed data which is in JSON format..What value did you want from that JSON Format?

Comment: You really can't find an example through searching google?

Comment: Ya in Xcode i have to pasre it to image view and Webview

Comment: @torjanfoe: No i couldnt and have not time it's top urgent- need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this. This is not the exact solution and you'll have to work around your way.

```
NSString *link =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourServiceURL"];
    NSString *encdLink = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:encdLink];
    NSData *response = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

Now you have your data in the array and extract it out using objectForKey or valueForKey.

This is what I am doing to fetch images from JSON and showing in my app. Firstly get the array from the above code. Then extract out the image content like this :

```
_ImageArray = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"ContentImage"];
```

Now you have the image name in your ImageArray.Since you have only imageName,you'll have to prepare the image URL in your code. Now to load the image in the ImageView, you need to do something like this.

```
NSURL *imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[_ImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
ImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageurl]];
```

This is for image. You can do it for the webview also. Some changes will be required as its a Webview. But it'll be done.

Comment: I have to parse the content in webview and image in Imageview, is there any solution for that ?

Comment: You will have to parse out the content and the image URL or image link, whichever you have in your app and then load respectively in web view and image view.

Comment: Btw, is your content a link or some file or something else ? If its text content, then probably you can display it in a Textview.

Comment: can u pls elaborate with the sample code if not mind

Comment: it contain HTML data in that content

Comment: See my updated answer, I have shown some code to fetch and display images.You can make out for web view in a similar way by doing some changes.

Comment: That is just an array. For storing multiple values. :)